# How to replace a Visual Studio Online/TFS WorkItem 's WorkItemHistory

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Using the API, I can get a work item, and add a comment (System.History item).

To get all history items I cannot quite see how to do it, except to use the obsolete GetHistoryAsync()

But the main problem I'm having is how to replace/update a WorkItemHistory for a given WorkItem.  I can see there are different revisions, but how do I specify in UpdateWorkItemAsync() that I want to update a specific revision?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the way to change work item history in VSTS. (Regarding TFS, you can modify data in database directly, but it isn’t recommended)

Also, it doesn’t make sense to modify work item history, the history is used to track the changes of work item.

Comment: I'm writing a syncing system, to migrate to VSTS, where this is needed.

Comment: @Nik, with TFS/VSTS API, you can't do it. If you want to migrate TFS to VSTS, you can use this tool: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration